# Seekbar does not update

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I want to play a music so I used seekber to show the progress, everything is fine until I press pause button, the seekbar stops but when I press the play button the seekbar does not move, I figured out it is because of getcurrentposition() method, it does not update after pausing, below is my code, what's wrong with it?

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    isPlaying = false;
                } else {
                    buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    isPlaying = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                onDestroy();
            }
        }
    }); 


 private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
    try {
        seekBarProgress
                .setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer
                        .getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100));
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: calling onDestroy(); in catch section ???

Comment: Replace onDestroy() by e.printStackTrace(). Replace e.printStackTrace() ONLY when you know that your code works fine. Possible that you have an NullPointer and you dont know it. By the way, why are you calling "onDestroy()" in the catch brackets? You should never call this manually. If you want an activity to end, just call finish().